Magento 2.4.7-p3 no such entity with cartId =
Suddenly started this strange and I can't figure out what is going on. Exception log is having every hour 3-4 errors in every minute like this:
2024-11-19T15:04:31.199036+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException: No such entity with cartId =  in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(250): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField()
#1 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(149): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->loadQuote()
#2 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->get()
#3 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callParent()
#4 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#5 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#6 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(181): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->get()
#7 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive()
#8 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php(79): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive()
#9 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider.php(76): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->getList()
#10 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider->getImages()
#11 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider\Interceptor->___callParent()
#12 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#13 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#14 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(347): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider\Interceptor->getImages()
#15 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#16 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callParent()
#17 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#18 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#19 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(39): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#20 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment-services-paypal/Block/SmartButtons.php(184): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
#21 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment-services-paypal/view/frontend/templates/smart_buttons_minicart.phtml(16): Magento\PaymentServicesPaypal\Block\SmartButtons->getSerializedCheckoutConfig()
#22 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(67): include('...')
#23 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render()
#24 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent()
#25 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#26 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#27 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render()
#28 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView()
#29 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1128): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#30 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1132): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#31 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(676): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#32 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#33 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock()
#34 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement()
#35 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement()
#36 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent()
#37 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#38 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(41): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#39 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(527): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement()
#40 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/ShortcutButtons.php(100): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml()
#41 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1128): Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons->_toHtml()
#42 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1132): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#43 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(676): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#44 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php(101): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#45 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart->getSectionData()
#46 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart\Interceptor->___callParent()
#47 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#48 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/CustomerData/Cart/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#49 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/SectionPool.php(90): Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart\Interceptor->getSectionData()
#50 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/SectionPool.php(60): Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool->getSectionDataByNames()
#51 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Section/Load.php(81): Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool->getSectionsData()
#52 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load->execute()
#53 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->___callParent()
#54 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#55 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Section/Load/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#56 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(111): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->execute()
#57 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch()
#58 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->___callParent()
#59 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#60 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Section/Load/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#61 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Customer\Controller\Section\Load\Interceptor->dispatch()
#62 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#63 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(146): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#64 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#65 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#66 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#67 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch()
#68 /home/public_html/vendor/amasty/aminvisiblecaptcha/Plugin/Framework/App/FrontControllerInterface/ValidateCaptcha.php(124): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#69 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Amasty\InvisibleCaptcha\Plugin\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface\ValidateCaptcha->aroundDispatch()
#70 /home/public_html/vendor/mirasvit/module-cache-warmer/src/CacheWarmer/Plugin/Debug/OnHitPlugin.php(145): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#71 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Mirasvit\CacheWarmer\Plugin\Debug\OnHitPlugin->aroundAroundDispatch()
#72 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#73 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#74 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch()
#75 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#76 /home/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#77 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#78 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#79 /home/public_html/pub/index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#80 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with cartId =  at /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"} []

This is there for 4 times and then stops. Then again.
My setup is with redis for sessions and for magento cache (not FPC). Also redis is used from php8.3 to save sessions.
Magento cookie settings are these:

and there is no session validation. Ajax cart is used with popup. Tried module from 3-4 major companies. Issue only stops when Ajax cart is disabled
Google tag manager also is used.
This is my env.php file:
<?php
return [
    'backend' => [
        'frontName' => 'admin'
    ],
    'db' => [
        'connection' => [
            'indexer' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'username' => 'magento',
                'password' => '000000000000',
                'active' => '1',
                'persistent' => null,
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;'
            ],
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'username' => 'magento',
                'password' => '00000000000000',
                'active' => '1',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'table_prefix' => ''
    ],
    'crypt' => [
        'key' => '0000000000000000000000000000000000000'
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ],
    'cache_types' => [
        'config' => 1,
        'layout' => 1,
        'block_html' => 1,
        'collections' => 1,
        'reflection' => 1,
        'db_ddl' => 1,
        'eav' => 1,
        'customer_notification' => 1,
        'config_integration' => 1,
        'config_integration_api' => 1,
        'target_rule' => 1,
        'full_page' => 1,
        'translate' => 1,
        'config_webservice' => 1,
        'compiled_config' => 1,
        'amasty_shopby' => 1,
        'graphql_query_resolver_result' => 1,
        'admin_ui_sdk' => 1
    ],
    'install' => [
        'date' => 'Mon, 11 Feb 2019 15:25:42 +0000'
    ],
    'system' => [
        'default' => [
            'dev' => [
                'debug' => [
                    'debug_logging' => '0'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'session' => [
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' => [
            'host' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
            'port' => '0',
            'password' => '',
            'timeout' => '2.5',
            'persistent_identifier' => '',
            'database' => '2',
            'compression_threshold' => '2048',
            'compression_library' => 'gzip',
            'log_level' => '1',
            'max_concurrency' => '100',
            'break_after_frontend' => '5',
            'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
            'first_lifetime' => '600',
            'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
            'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
            'disable_locking' => '0',
            'min_lifetime' => '60',
            'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
            'sentinel_master' => '',
            'sentinel_servers' => '',
            'sentinel_connect_retries' => '5',
            'sentinel_verify_master' => '0'
        ]
    ],
    'cache' => [
        'frontend' => [
            'default' => [
                'backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\RemoteSynchronizedCache',
                'backend_options' => [
                    'remote_backend' => '\\Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
                    'remote_backend_options' => [
                        'persistent' => 0,
                        'server' => '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
                        'database' => '0',
                        'port' => '0',
                        'password' => '',
                        'compress_data' => '1',
                        'preload_keys' => [
                            '358_EAV_ENTITY_TYPES',
                            '358_GLOBAL_PLUGIN_LIST',
                            '358_DB_IS_UP_TO_DATE',
                            '358_SYSTEM_DEFAULT'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'local_backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_File',
                    'local_backend_options' => [
                        'cache_dir' => '/dev/shm/'
                    ],
                    'use_stale_cache' => false
                ],
                'frontend_options' => [
                    'write_control' => false
                ],
                'id_prefix' => 'a31_'
            ],
            'page_cache' => [
                'id_prefix' => 'a313_'
            ]
        ],
        'type' => [
            'default' => [
                'frontend' => 'default'
            ]
        ],
        'graphql' => [
            'id_salt' => '00000000000000000000000000000000000'
        ],
        'allow_parallel_generation' => false
    ],
    'queue' => [
        'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0,
        'amqp' => [
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => '5672',
            'user' => 'guest',
            'password' => 'guest',
            'virtualhost' => '/',
            'ssl' => ''
        ]
    ],
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 0,
        'single_thread' => true,
        'consumers-wait-for-messages' => 0,
        'consumers' => [
            'product_action_attribute.update',
            'product_action_attribute.website.update',
            'codegeneratorProcessor',
            'exportProcessor',
            'quoteItemCleaner',
            'async.operations.all',
            'inventoryQtyCounter',
            'media.content.synchronization',
            'media.gallery.renditions.update',
            'media.gallery.synchronization',
            'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage',
            'media.storage.catalog.image.resize',
            'matchCustomerSegmentProcessor',
            'sales.rule.quote.trigger.recollect',
            'staging.synchronize_entity_period',
            'product_alert',
            'placeOrderProcessor',
            'inventory.source.items.cleanup',
            'inventory.mass.update',
            'inventory.reservations.cleanup',
            'inventory.reservations.update',
            'inventory.reservations.updateSalabilityStatus',
            'inventory.indexer.sourceItem',
            'inventory.indexer.stock'
        ]
    ],
    'indexer' => [
        'use_application_lock' => true,
        'batch_size' => [
            'catalogsearch_fulltext' => [
                'partial_reindex' => 100,
                'mysql_get' => 500,
                'elastic_save' => 500
            ],
            'catalog_product_price' => [
                'simple' => 1000,
                'default' => 500,
                'configurable' => 1000
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'remote_storage' => [
        'driver' => 'file'
    ],
    'http_cache_hosts' => [
        [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '80'
        ]
    ],
    'lock' => [
        'provider' => 'db'
    ],
    'directories' => [
        'document_root_is_pub' => true
    ],
    'checkout' => [
        'async' => 0,
        'deferred_total_calculating' => 0
    ]
];

What I did but didnt' work:

Redis session_locking on\off and max_concurrency
Removed redis from env.php session and made php save session to files
Disable tag manager
Tried different Ajax carts

Issue stops only with native magento cart without Ajax
I can't figure out how to debug it and I am very worried because I believe that we have clients who add products to cart the when they go to cart or checkout, it is empty.
That's very bad for our store.
Any ideas please? Is there a way to debug this random issue?

We’re very interested in this issue as well. We encountered it after our recent Magento upgrade.

@obsergiu could you please provide your magento setup? And which modules you use for Ajax cart?

Same error here after upgrading Adobe PS, and Magento 2.47-p3.
Has Payment Services been made aware of this so they can fix it in their next update or issue a patch?

Also stumbled upon this error recently and trying to debug it right now.
As it seems the error comes from the Paypal-Express Button in the minicart. To me it looks like it's tried to load the minicart, or at least some configurations for the paypal button that require a quote already at the very first visit of the page when the user has no cart yet. And therefore it runs into that exception.
So, it shouldn't be a problem for the customers, it just causes that exceptions as long as the users have no cart.
Still unpleasant since it spams our exception.log, so I'm trying to get rid of it and will keep you updated.
Update: ok, doesn't seem to appear at every visit, but when changing between storeviews. So not sure how exactly it's triggered, but it seems it works when I change the following line in function getSectionData() of vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php
old:
'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons::class)->toHtml(),

new:
'extra_actions' => $this->getSummaryCount() ? $this->layout->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons::class)->toHtml() : null,

so, whenever the sectionData is requested, get the Shortcut Buttons (that contain the Paypal Button which is triggering the error) only when at least one product is in cart.
Of course don't change the core file directly!!!
I'd suggest to use a composer patch that alters that line of the corefile.

Hi. Good catch! Although I do not use Paypal Express button. But I use Stripe Apple and Google Play buttons. Do you think is the same? Also I have only 1 store view. The second is disabled for now

In your stack trace the paypal button also pops up:
#20 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/module-payment-services-paypal/Block/SmartButtons.php(184): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
So probably that code is also run through even if the button is deactivated.
And seems there's other ways that trigger that exception besides switching storeviews, but that patch should help anyway. Doesn't fix the root cause, since I didn't figure out yet what causes it but it should prevent the exception from being thrown and shouldn't have any side effects. At least I hope so.

I also have the same error, in my case it started after I updated Adobe Payment Services from version v2.8.1 to v2.9.0, and I had to revert the upgrade.
Recently, the Adobe Payment Services v 2.10.0 was released, but after installing it the error returned.
Looking at the error logs, apparently the error is related to the PayPal portion of the module.
For now, I am sticking with the old v2.8.1
